# Passing special characters to an MVC 5 controller with javascript parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to allow the user to edit names in an MVC application.

The controller function has this signature:

```
[Route("function/edit/{id:int}/{name}/{sortorder:int}")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string name, int sortorder)
{...}
```

I am calling it in Javascript like this:

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Edit", "Function")" + "/" + id + "/" + name + "/" + order;
```

It all works fine, until the name contains '/' or the name ends with a '.' then i get a "The resource cannot be found." from the server.
This makes perfect sense, since the '/' and '.' characters rightly confuses the routing...

But how should i do this?? I want to allow '/' and '.' in the names.

Comment: I already tried encodeURIComponent and escape.  
None of them do anything about '.' or '/'

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode the data so characters such as `/` are passed correctly. For this you should use the [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) function:

```
window.location.href = 
    "@Url.Action("Edit", "Function")" + "/" + id + "/" + 
        encodeURIComponent(name) + "/" + order;
```

For example, this is the difference before and after encoding:

```js
var test = "this.is/a test";
alert(test);
alert(encodeURIComponent(test));
```

Additional to this, your MVC application is also having issues due to the way it decodes the URL. One solution to this is to reorder the parameters in your route to have the `name` value last and give it a catch-all modifier:

```
[Route("function/edit/{id:int}/{sortorder:int}/{*name}")]
```

This forces MVC routing to pick up the last part as the entire value for `name`.

Comment: encodeURIComponent(name) doesn't do anything about '.' or '/'

Comment: @JakobOlsen Yes it does, see the link which specifically states it encodes the `/` and the edit I have made with an example.

Comment: My bad... It does in fact encode '/'. It doesn't solve the problem though. I still get the "The resource cannot be found." error even when the / is encoded

Comment: @JakobOlsen So you do need the encoding, but I've also made an edit for an MVC specific issue too.

Comment: Nice suggestions, but it still doesn't work. I think the problem may be, that the url is decoded before the routing even sees it.  
If i want the name to be "allan / bert", then the mvc-routing will see the url "function/edit/1/2/allan / bert" even if it was url-encoded when recieved.

Comment: @JakobOlsen Strange. I've tested it here with normal routing (i.e. not attribute routing) and it works fine.

Comment: @JakobOlsen Just tried with attribute routing and it worked for me. Did you add the `*` prefix to `name` in the route?

Comment: Yes i did. I have solved the problem by first urlencoding the name, then replacing the '%' with something else. This means that the routing works as intended. I then need to manually replace back to '%' and url-decode in the MVC controller.
Not exactly elegant... I hope to find a better solution at some point :-(